# Firebase value callback breaking ReactJS component on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS with Firebase (very cool combo). My root React component listens for a `value` event on the root firebase and re-renders each time with the new data.

A nested component has a `touchstart` listener that looks like this:

```
var leaf = new Firebase(...);
leaf.remove();

document.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleTouchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchend', this._handleTouchEnd);

this.setState({
    startX: e.touches[0].pageX,
    startY: e.touches[0].pageY,
});
```

This does three things:

- The `leaf` points to a child of the firebase the root component is listening to. So when `remove()` is called, a `value` is triggered at the top level and react renders.
- The touch position is added to the child components state.
- And event listeners are added to the document for `touchmove` and `touchend`.

This works perfectly on desktop using equivalent mouse events. The `mousedown` event removes the leaf from firebase, the state is set with the initial mouse position and then `mousemove` and `mouseup` listeners use that state to do their thing.

This also works perfectly if I remove the firebase call to `remove()`. The state is updated, and `touchmove` and `touchend` do their thing.

The trouble is the `touchmove` and `touchend` listeners on mobile never fire.

Anyone have an idea what might be going on here?